# How to parse JSON obtained from HttpClient connection?

Tags: android

I have successfully established a connection using Httpclient `GET` method. Now I want to parse the data using JSON Parser. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the org.json package in the Android SDK. It has useful classes like JSONObject and JSONArray that you can use to parse JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JSONObject` class as Rahul said. Its quite good.

Read more about it [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

General information about JSON: [here](http://www.json.org/)